# wsimport from https: [ERROR] java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present

Tags: java, web-services, soap, https, wsimport

I'm trying to generate a webservice client using wsimport from https wsdl:

```
call wsimport -d bin -s src -p mypackage.ws https://x.x.x.x:8181/services/SomeService?wsdl
```

For solving security errors I added a server's certificate to Java's keystore:

```
keytool -import -keystore c:\Java\jdk1.6.0_38\jre\lib\security\cacerts -file c:\ca-dev.crt
```

But when I do wsimport error appears:

**[ERROR] java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present**

**Failed to read the WSDL document: https://x.x.x.x:8181/services/SomeService?wsdl, because 1) could not find the document; /2) the document could not
be read; 3) the root element of the document is not .**

**[ERROR] failed.noservice=Could not find wsdl:service in the provided WSDL(s):**

**At least one WSDL with at least one service definition needs to be provided**.

```
    Failed to parse the WSDL.
```

**SOLVED!**
Added entry with name same as certificate's CN to hosts file.

Comment: Added entry with name same as certificate's CN to hosts file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An SSL certificate is based on hostnames.  Either the certificate's CN must be the hostname you are trying to access, or it must have an optional Subject Alternative Name entry which exactly matches the hostname you are trying to access.

If possible, make sure the hostname in your https URL exactly matches the CN or one of the Subject Alternative Names in the certificate.  Many certificates have no Subject Alternative Names, so don't stress if you can't find any when you examine the certificate.

Sometimes referring to the hostname in this manner isn't possible, such as when port 8181 is only accessible inside a LAN and referring to the machine by its full and proper hostname would use an Internet route to reach it.  As far as I know, there is no command-line means of disabling certificate checking.  One (obviously non-portable) workaround is to add an entry to your `hosts` file, which is typically located at `%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` in Windows, so you can refer to the server with the hostname that is in the certificate.

Comment: while import for the certificate it asks for password, i cannot ask the third party for the password.

Please Assist me on this .

Comment: I have added the ip address of the web server to the hosts file and mapped it to the CN to the certificate and changed the WSDL url to have the ip address instead of the server name. Now, I get the No Subject Alternative Names error. How to I resolve this.

Comment: The WSDL URL needs to use a hostname that exactly matches the CN of the certificate.

Comment: The CN of the certificate has spaces in it (e.g. CN=ABC Inc). In the host file I have mapped the ip to this CN and enclosed the CN in "" (x.x.x.x   "ABC Inc"). The problem is that I cannot use the CN with spaces in the URL of the WSDL to access the WSDL from the server. wsimport "https://ABC Inc/ABCService?wsdl"

Comment: the last line should have been wsimport '"https://ABC Inc/ABCService?wsdl"'. the https:// is missing from the URL. I hope you get the idea.

Comment: As I said in the second sentence of my answer, the CN *must* be the hostname.  Not a company name.  You will need to either get the certificate re-issued with a different CN, or get a new certificate.