# Unable to create the stub using the wsimport?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, wsdl

I'm trying to create the stub using the WSDL.
 but the Web services are using the SSL, so i used 
`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\security>keytool -import -file my_home
.crt` 
to import the necessary certificates to the key store. but when i try to execute the `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin>wsimport -keep -s c:\SEI\ https://16.175.217.24:8443/cfcc/control?view=services/AdministratorService?WSDL
parsing WSDL...` I'm getting below errors.
 ` parsing WSDL...

```
 [ERROR] java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names pr
esent

Failed to read the WSDL document: https://16.175.217.24:8443/cfcc/control?view=s
ervices/AdministratorService?WSDL, because 1) could not find the document; /2) t
he document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <wsdl:
definitions>.


[ERROR] failed.noservice=Could not find wsdl:service in the provided WSDL(s):

At least one WSDL with at least one service definition needs to be provided.


    Failed to parse the WSDL.
```

. `
Please help me with to find the root cause of the error?

Thanks in advance.
sushma.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456789/wsimport-from-https-error-java-security-cert-certificateexception-no-subject I think its a similar issue.

Comment: @Karthikeyan i tried your solution also, still it is not working. CN = 16.175.217.24 if i try it via URL it is working but via wsimport it is not working. One more information while accessing via URL it is asking for the username/password then giving the WSDL. While using wsimport is it making any problems? Could you please help me with it?